# Passing data from php to JavaScript for Gutenberg Block with editor Script registered via block.json

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I am building a custom Gutenberg block an register the editor script as recommended in the block.json file.

```
"editorScript": "file:./index.js",
```

Now I would like to pass data from php to Javascript using the [wp_add_inline_script()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_add_inline_script/) function. However this requires the handle of the script. In the block.json I don't name a handle and there doesn't seem to be a possibility to do it.

Is there something like a default handle? Or is there another way to pass data from my php plugin file to JavaScript (I want to pass the plugin directory path).

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `wp_add_inline_script()` is used for passing data from PHP to JavaScript, including Gutenberg blocks.

The script handle you are looking for is the name of your block with the `/` replaced with a `-`, eg:

**block.json**

```json
{
    "name": "my/blockname",
    "editorScript": "file:./index.js",
    ...
}
```

**my-block.php**

```php
function my_blockname_add_inline_script()
{
    // Plugin path for my block
    $path = plugin_dir_url(__FILE__);

    $handle = 'my-blockname'; // name from block.json with a '-' instead of '/'
    $data = 'const myBlockPath ="' . $path . '";';
    $position = 'before';

    wp_add_inline_script($handle, $data, $position);
}


/**
 * Registers the block using the metadata loaded from the `block.json` file.
 */
function my_blockname_block_init() {
    register_block_type( __DIR__ . '/build' );

    // Enqueue script after register_block_type() so script handle is valid
    add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_blockname_add_inline_script');
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_blockname_add_inline_script');
}

add_action( 'init', 'my_blockname_block_init' );
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I figured out that the actual handle I was looking for is "my-blockname-editor-script". Maybe this depends on the way you register and structure your block?!? I am using wordpress/scripts and when I create a block it automatically generates separate files of the edit and the save function. The name you suggested might be valid in other cases. Couldn't really find any documentation on this topic...

Comment: @Eingenetzt No worries, I haven't really found it in the documentation either. By using "my-blockname" I add the JS to both the frontend & editor for my block, though "my-blockname-editor-script" makes sense to target the editor script - good to know that it works!

Comment: I don't think that there are any scripts loaded in the frontend for a block unless I specifically load one (and give it a hook). There is only a css file and html from the database. Again this may vary depending on the specific setup... Talking about wordpress/scripts standard setup.

Comment: I'm doing this from a plugin, and the handle naming convention for me was (PHP syntax) `'plugin-name' . '-' . 'file-name' . '-' . 'script'`. E.g, if my plugin was called 'cool-plugin' and my view script file name was 'view-public' then my handle passed to wp_add_inline_script() would be: 'cool-plugin-view-public-script'. WP 6.4.2.